# How do I figure out what cluster helm installed on Google GKE?

Tags: kubernetes, helm, google-kubernetes-engine

When I run a command like

```
helm install MyApp
```

How do I know what cluster it will install too using Google GKE?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Helm just uses whatever your kube config is set to, you can see that with,

```
kubectl config current-context
```

Or you can view the raw config with

```
kubectl config view
```

And it should be listed as `current-context`